# Error detection algorithm for a URL

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, web, error-handling

I was wondering about some possible ideas on how I can implement an error detection algorithm for a URL. My url can work as follows:

```
http://changes.html?Type=Production&Item=Tires&Type=Winter

My Url can have the following forms:

http://changes.html?Type=Production //which gets you to the base page

http://changes.html?Type=Production&Item=Tires //which gives you all the tire options

http://changes.html?Type=Production&Item=Tires&Type=Winter //which gives you a specific tire
```

My question here is that say I spelled Type=Production wrong in a way such that I spelled it as `Tzxpe=Poductaion` then I may think of having a default page. Also if say everything is correct until Type such that you have the following URL:

`http://changes.html?Type=Production&Item=Tires&TZAe=Wter` then I am thinking of just cutting off the string at Tires until where its correct and programming a page re-direct to that working part. My solutions seem a bit odd and inefficient. Is there a better way to perhaps have the URL fix itself, or yet even a better implementation of my idea, or just a completely different way of approaching this problem? Error checking is a must for this project so just receiving a bad url message is not going to cut it!

Comment: Why is error checking so important?  Typically these URLs won't be typed directly to the bar, surely?

Comment: COuld you use a regExp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question but what you could do would be to split the URL you receive on the back end on `?` `=` and `&` and then check the values for `Type` against possible correct values (an enum class or just an array of predefined possibilities) and the same with `Item`. This is dependent on how you are dealing with your service calls though.

I don't know that regex is entirely a good idea. You are looking to make sure things are spelled right which doesn't really fit regex in my experience.

Comment: the options that I have are coming out of a databse that contains around 10000+ values that increase on a daily basis.

Comment: @user3767481 Checking against the database is your best bet cause otherwise what you seem to be talking about is a spell check algorithm